# matplotlib does not work

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I have a code looks like below. The whole code is doing plot two raster images scatter plot see the correlations. But the error message keep telling me valueerror:x and y must be the same size. i am pretty sure the x and y and same size. can somebody help with it

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import netCDF4 as net
import numpy as np
hailprob=net.Dataset("/ab20140723.nc")
hailsize=net.Dataset("ailI20140723L3C_CONUS.nc")
hp=hailprob.variables['HailProb'][:]
hs=hailsize.variables['HailIndx'][:]
hp=np.array(hp)
hp1=np.where(hp>0)
hs=np.array(hs)
hs1=np.where(hs>0)
hp2=hp[hp1]
hs2=hs[hs1]
hp2.flatten()
hs2.flatten()
plt.scatter(hp2,hs2) 
main_title="scatter plot"
plt.title(main_title,loc='center')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.tick_param(which='major',direction='in',length=6,width=2)
plt.tick_params(which='minor', direction='in', length=4, width=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `i am pretty sure the x and y and same size.` - well then print them out in your code and prove it :)

Comment: so i print them it, they are different size. What should i do to plot them then

Comment: Well, guess! Make them the same size.

Comment: i can not. the thing is i need to plot only values that are greater than zero. The two images are exactly same extent.

Comment: The extent no longer matters when you only take certain values. Unless both images have the same number of >0 pixels hp2 and hs2 will never be the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter pairs of values where either hp or hs are smaller or equal to zero, then you can do something like the following:

```
mask = (hp > 0) & (hs > 0)
hp = hp[mask]
hs = hs[mask]
```

In this way you select the same values from both arrays, so the final flattened arrays should have the same size.

Comment: thank you so much. I have another question. What if i want to add a y percentile as either a line or dot on the existing plot for example like 20% according to different x values?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. You have a lot of points with exactly the same x value and you want to put a point after the 20% percentile of y values ordered ascendingly?